# Truffle console keep showing "undefined". Solved by rolling back to v4 stable

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-console

I have updated my truffle version to the latest `v5.0.3`. By running `truffle version`, I can get the following version statements.

```
Truffle v5.0.3 (core: 5.0.3)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.8.0
```

However, this update stops me from executing some tutorials that were supposed to work. Especially, the ZOS tutorial at https://docs.zeppelinos.org/docs/upgrading.html, when running commands `myContract.x().toString()` in Truffle Console. Instead of showing a numerical result, the console kept showing `undefined`. The same problem happened for the case of running `myContract.s()`.

I am not sure whether the problem comes from a different use of cli command sets across versions. It took me hours to fix it. Therefore, if you encountered similar problems, I wish it can save you time.

Comment: The expression `myContract.x()` should return a promise, which when resolved, yields a `BigNumber` instance (or on Truffle 5, possibly a `BN` instance, due to the upgrade of web3 version). I'm not sure why this works for you on Truffle 4, but you should generally resolve the promise before calling `toString()`. You can do this, for example, with `(await myContract.x()).toString()`.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for the great comment. That's right. The promise can be successfully returned when at Truffle v4, but it failed at Truffle v5 which turned out to return `undefined` constantly.

Comment: @goodvibration I tried out `(await myContract.x()).toString()`, which returned `TypeError: myContract.x is not a function`. And `(await myContract.x)` returned `undefined`. Interesting haha.

Comment: Try `myContract.methods.x`. Truffle 5.x relies on web3 1.x, which dictates this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade the Truffle version to the stable version of `v4`. And everything works like usual.

**Reinstall Truffle**

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
npm i -g truffle@4
```

**Check Truffle Version**

```
truffle version
```

which will return

```
Truffle v4.1.15 (core: 4.1.15)
Solidity v0.4.25 (solc-js)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The expression `myContract.x()` returns a promise, which when resolved, yields a `BigNumber` instance. You should generally resolve the promise before calling `toString()`. You can do this, for example, with `(await myContract.x()).toString()`.
2. When you upgrade Truffle version from 4.x to 5.x, the underlying Web3 version is subsequently upgraded from 0.x to 1.x. This version of Web3 dictates the syntax `myContract.methods.myFunc()`, so you should use `myContract.methods.x()`.